# How to use tabulate lib with float64 : python

Tags: python, kaggle

In order to pretty print the data, I am using `tabulate` library in python. 
Here is the code I am using :

```
train = pd.read_csv('../misc/data/train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('../misc/data/test.csv')

# Prints the head of data prettily :)
print(tabulate(train.head(), headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

The data is titanic dataset from kaggle. Now, I need to use tabulate on data that has float64 values. Here is the code that's giving me the error:

```
surv_age = train[train['Survived'] == 1]['Age'].value_counts()
dead_age = train[train['Survived'] == 0]['Age'].value_counts()

print(tabulate(surv_age, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))

df = pd.DataFrame([surv_age, dead_age])
df.index = ['Survived', 'Dead']
df.plot(kind='hist', stacked=True, figsize=(15, 8))
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Number of passengers')
plt.show()
```

The error is: 
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "main.py", line 49, in <module>
    print(tabulate(surv_age, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tabulate.py", line 1109, in tabulate
    tabular_data, headers, showindex=showindex)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tabulate.py", line 741, in _normalize_tabular_data
    rows = [list(row) for row in vals]
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

Line 49 is the `print(tabulate(..` line from the code.

How do I iterate `float64` values of data so that I can pretty print in tabulate? If its not possible in `tabulate`, please suggest an alternative way of pretty printing that can do so. Here is the sample of what tabulate can do :

```
+----+---------------+------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------+-------+---------+---------+------------------+---------+---------+------------+
|    |   PassengerId |   Survived |   Pclass | Name                                                | Sex    |   Age |   SibSp |   Parch | Ticket           |    Fare | Cabin   | Embarked   |
|----+---------------+------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------+-------+---------+---------+------------------+---------+---------+------------|
|  0 |             1 |          0 |        3 | Braund, Mr. Owen Harris                             | male   |    22 |       1 |       0 | A/5 21171        |  7.25   | nan     | S          |
|  1 |             2 |          1 |        1 | Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer) | female |    38 |       1 |       0 | PC 17599         | 71.2833 | C85     | C          |
|  2 |             3 |          1 |        3 | Heikkinen, Miss. Laina                              | female |    26 |       0 |       0 | STON/O2. 3101282 |  7.925  | nan     | S          |
|  3 |             4 |          1 |        1 | Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)        | female |    35 |       1 |       0 | 113803           | 53.1    | C123    | S          |
|  4 |             5 |          0 |        3 | Allen, Mr. William Henry                            | male   |    35 |       0 |       0 | 373450           |  8.05   | nan     | S          |
+----+---------------+------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------+-------+---------+---------+------------------+---------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: Could you add the `tabulate()` code?

Comment: https://github.com/gregbanks/python-tabulate

Comment: I am sorry but I haven't read the library's code. I will check and tell you.

Comment: my bad, I didn't read the question correctly

Comment: It seems like `surv_age` is wrong in some way. Could you print it's shape or something?

Comment: It says (342,). The shape is alright I guess

Comment: I think you will need to reshape it into a 2D array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the [`tabulate`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) documentation,

> The following tabular data types are supported:
>
> - list of lists or another iterable of iterables
> - list or another iterable of dicts (keys as columns)
> - dict of iterables (keys as columns)
> - two-dimensional NumPy array
> - NumPy record arrays (names as columns)
> - pandas.DataFrame

Your variable `surv_age` is a 1-D numpy array of shape (342,). You will need to re-shape into a 2-D numpy array. You can do this easily using [`numpy.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html),

```
surv_age = np.reshape(surv_age, (-1, 1))
```

You can also do this using [`np.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) like this,

```
surv_age = np.expand_dims(surv_age, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. How can I limit the size of array being printed? I tried using surv_age[:20][0], but it's giving error saying `numpy.float64` has no len()

Comment: How about `surv_age[:20,:]`?

Comment: Also, could you try this? `pd.DataFrame([surv_age])`? I suspect this will work too

Comment: The pd.dataframe doesn't work. I had tried that before, it gives an output which is certainly not a table but loads of + and - and then the data. Also, I can't limit the size of array displayed after using dataframe. It says : `unhashable type`

Comment: Can you please explain why surv_age[:20, 0], and surv_age[:20][0] don't work?

Comment: Both those techniques won't leave 2-D arrays. Try to print the `shape` of the resultant array after each of those function calls

Comment: Wow, the access syntax changes the shape of Python list sent .